# How to send a verification code to an email id

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I have developed An App using Unity 2018 which have a text box to receive email id from users and have a submit button… I wants that when user enter email id in textbox and click on submit button, the **verification code** should go to the user email id in the form of an email… How to do this?

I have done Firebase phone number verification (Firebase sms is receiving in my phone using Firebase).

Verification code should go to the user email id...

Did Firebase Supports Emailing the Verification code to the user or

Is there any service available for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can send out an email verification through the Unity Firebase SDK. You wont need to use a verification code in your app as once the user clicks on the link in their email it will be verified. You can check if its verified through the SDK in the users object.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;
if (user != null) {
  user.SendEmailVerificationAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsCanceled) {
      Debug.LogError("SendEmailVerificationAsync was canceled.");
      return;
    }
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
      Debug.LogError("SendEmailVerificationAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
      return;
    }

    Debug.Log("Email sent successfully.");
  });
}
```